# How to handle bounce email messages when you send emails on behalf of customer

Tags: c#, email, smtp, email-bounces

I need advice on processing/tracking bounce emails.
We have a scenario, where we need to send emails to recipient on behalf of our customers.
lets say we need to send email to user@recipient.com with from as emailer@cusotmer.com but when this email fails we need to receive the bounce/failure notification on mybouncetracker@mydomain.com

I tried using the reply-to/return-path but both getting replaced with emailer@cusotmer.com.
We were not able to process bounce message as we dont own the inbox for emailer@cusotmer.com.

Please help!!..

We created smtp client on C#.net

Comment: reply to is getting overwritten by the Mail from...

Answer (score 1):

Please be advised that we can't rely on the reply-to headers or inserting a custom ID to our original message's headers since the bounced messages returned by the mail servers vary from server to server. Many of them just bounced with a plain-text saying that the delivery is failed without including the original message.

My advise is to use Regex with compiled options (for performance) to scan the messages.

After you have read the message content, you can use the following code to classify a message as a soft bounce that states that the message sending was failed:

```
string pattern = "failed after \S+ sent[\s\n]the[\s\n]message";
Regex regexPattern = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);

if (regexPattern.Match(myMessage.BodyHtml))
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is a soft bounce");
}
```

You can add more patterns to classify more messages.